# How self variable works,when class is assigned to instance variables

Tags: python, robotframework

I came across following piece of code in robot framework.
variable are assigned with different class name.
https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/variables/variables.py

```
def __init__(self):
    self.store = VariableStore(self)
    self._replacer = VariableReplacer(self)
    self._finder = VariableFinder(self.store)
```

To understand how does above assignment work,i wrote following piece of code,which is throwing error when using self

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def addition(self):
    return 5

class boo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.word = Foo(self)  

    def multiply(self):
        return self.word.addition()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = boo()
    print(b.multiply())  #TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

When using following combination in boo() class,getting the correct output i.e. 5.

1. self.word=Foo;return self.word.addition(self)
2. self.word=Foo();return self.word.addition()

Comment: How could multiply work as it's not present in class `Foo` (at least accordingly to your code, maybe formatting?) Furthermore, `boo` cannot be created, as `Foo` takes no arguments in __init__ and it will throw `TypeError` as seen in the comment. What is the actual problem here?

Comment: `Foo` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: You are mis-reading the error. You didn't share your traceback, but I bet it is not pointing at the `print()` line, but at the `b = boo()` line instead, followed by `self.word = Foo(self)`.

Comment: Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/89a9b80bcbf697bbcc883b21fb8afea1331027d8/src/robot/variables/store.py#L25) for the `VariableStore` constructor. It takes the bound argument `self` and one positional argument `variables`. Invoking it as `VariableStore(self)` is actually equivalent to `VariableStore(variables=self)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,here is the traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dell/PycharmProjects/Meetup/project1.py", line 25, in <module>
    b = boo()
  File "C:/Users/dell/PycharmProjects/Meetup/project1.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.word = Foo(self)  #class as constructor
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @SzymonMaszke,could you please help me to understand "Furthermore, boo cannot be created, as Foo takes no arguments in init "

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `def __init__(self)` inside the `Foo` class. You have as the parameter `self`, but, just like any other method, it doesn't have to be specifically passed in. So in the `boo` constructor, when you say `self.word = Foo(self)`, you're actually calling `__init__` of `Foo` with two arguments; the inherent `self` and the `self` of `boo` you're passing. That explains why you're getting the error of `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong with your interpretation of what is happening. First, let's look at the code and the error you're getting:

```
b = boo()
print(b.multiply())  #TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Your comment seems to imply you think the error is happening when you call `b.multiply()`. However, when you look at the stack trace you'll see it happens when you do `b = boo()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/junk.py", line 16, in <module>
    b = boo()
  File "/tmp/junk.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.word = Foo(self)  
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Note that the stack trace is telling you precisely what the problem is. You've defined `Foo.__init__` to take a single parameter but two are being given. Why are two being given? When you create an instance of a class in python, python automatically passes in the `self` parameter. In other words, if you do `b=boo()`, your function will automatically get `self` without you having to explicitly pass it in. This is a very fundamental part of python's design. It has nothing to do with robot framework.

In trying to replicate the robot code, you've created a class named `Foo` that takes a single parameter named `self`. However, the `VariableStore` object takes *two* parameters: `self` and `variables`:

```
class VariableStore(object):   
    def __init__(self, variables):
        ...
```

Remember, python will automatically pass in `self`, so the first argument you pass in will get associated with the `variables` parmeter.

Consider this line of code:

```
self.store = VariableStore(self)
```

Based on how `VariableStore` is defined, it is exactly the same as this:

```
self.store = VariableStore(variables=self)
```

Notice how `self` is *not* the same as the `self` parameter of the `__init__`. It is passed to the `variables` parameter. This is because python automatically passes `self` as the first parameter when constructing a class.